# Why or why not is this constraint style available under the OWL OWA? Is there a standard workaround?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, semantic-web

I have this hierarchy in Protege 5:

```
Class: Song  
----->subclass: HappySong  
equivalent: Song and (HasWord exactly 0 SadWord) and (HasWord some HappyWord) and (HasWord min 0 NeutralWord)
  

----->subclass: SadSong  
equivalent: Song and (HasWord some SadWord) and (HasWord exactly 0 HappyWord) and (HasWord min 0 NeutralWord)  
    

Class: Word  
----->subclass: HappyWord  
----->subclass: SadWord  
----->subclass: NeutralWord  


DataProperty: hasWord  
----->domain: Song  
----->range: Word  


Intances of Song:  

song_1:  
HasWord joy (instance of HappyWord)  
HasWord meh (instance of NeutralWord)  

song_2:  
HasWord boohoo (instance of SadWord)  
HasWord meh (instance of NeutralWord)  
HasWord loss (instance of SadWord)  

song_3:  
HasWord boohoo (instance of SadWord)  
HasWord meh (instance of NeutralWord)  
HasWord loss (instance of SadWord)  
HasWord joy (instance of HappyWord)
```

I am running the Hermit reasoner (and tried others) and this is apparently inconsistent. I thought this ontology would allow me to infer song_1 as a HappySong, song_2 as sad, and song_3 as still just song since it can not satisfy the constraints of class membership. After this I want to throw it into graphDB and look at shared neutral words, common words etc. with SPARQL queries.

What is the problem with how I have implemented these class constraints and is this sort of constraints possible to implement in Protege 5? If so, how?

Comment: I guess you're just misunderstanding OWL - it doesn't have a concept of "constraints" it's all about inference, i.e. inferring implicit statements from the explicit ones. And yes, the Open World Assumption is the "problem" here. So, basically OWL is the wrong approach to model constraints, languages like SHACL, SheX have been designed for this task.

Comment: By the way, we had a similar question with the the same domain some days ago, are you guys doing a university assignment? Unfortunately, the TO deleted the question, it's a weird trend in the past days. The idea is to keep knowledge for other users, like you for example

Comment: Yes, that other question was me, but it was ambiguous, and I ended it to make this question which I feel better captures my specific misunderstanding of OWL OWA. Can surely undelete.

Comment: So in OWL/OWA I can only infer based on what relationships an entity "does have" in the ontology, as opposed to my constraints (which work by considering what relations an entity "doesn't have")? I think so, because I tried removing all axioms of type (max 0, not( has some), exactly 0) and it classifies correctly. After I populate, could I potentially use sparql to query "shapes" in the rdf, or do I still need to use shacl?

Comment: Sure, you could also formulate your constraints via SPARQL queries and check for violations

Comment: Am I right in conceptualizing SHACL shapes as akin to making ontology classes out of info constraints that were traditionally obtained via SPARQL queries? Or are there other clear advantages to SHACL?

Comment: You say that "this is apparently inconsistent", but is it? Based on what you show, there is no way it can be inconsistent. However, you write that "hasWord" is a DataProperty, but in this case, it cannot have "Word" as a range. So either you do not show exactly what's in the ontology, or your ontology is not a proper OWL 2 DL ontology and HermiT cannot reason with it at all.

Comment: Assuming that you simply wrote "DataProperty" by mistake when you actually mean "ObjectProperty", then it is quite intuitive that noone can make any conclusion about song 1, 2 and 3. Making any conclusion about a song because you know just 2 or 3 words in it would be insane. Why would semantic web reasoner be designed to draw insane conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

Because of OWL OWA (Open World Assumption), one needs to use SHACL or Shex (as noted by –UninformedUser) to define groups of individuals by what attributes they lack (constraints).